# access sails app from any client

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I have a really strange problem. I have a sails app running on my local machine and want to access this application from another computer within the same network, but I get a timeout.

not that I think that it should be necessary, but I even configured cors in `config/cors.js`:

```
allRoutes: true,
origin: '*',
credentials: true,
methods: 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD',
headers: 'content-type'
```

My project is pretty empty, I just created a few models/controllers and thats it.

I didn't find anything about this problem in their manual so I guess I must have done something wrong during my project setup. Has anyone an idea on how to fix this?

**edit**
just to make sure I didn't do something completely wront I just created a new project

```
sails new foo
cd foo
sails lift
```

-> http://192.168.1.12:1337

works from localhost, gets a timeout from any other host in the network

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually taking for granted that you already tried to ping your host machine from the other machine and you successfully managed to get a response.

If so, I suggest [ngrok](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngrok) package to gain access for other users to your local machine. [Ngrok](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngrok) exposes your localhost to the web, and has an NPM wrapper that is simple to install and start:

```
$ npm install ngrok -g
$ ngrok http 1337
```

The last command will print in the console the new address that points to localhost:1337

Edit: By the way, I'm pretty sure your problem is about network configurations and not sails configurations.